# Directly calling last Item of the ArrayList

Tags: java, android, arrays, arraylist

I am using *`String Arrays`* to perform some task [assume to *play videos*] in a correct sequence and it ***works*** as per the `expectations`, see the below code:

```
    String[] videoUriList = {str1, str2, str3};

    if(null != videoUriList && videoUriList.length > 1) {
                // Plays the first video, then the second video.
                mediaSource = new ConcatenatingMediaSource(
                        buildMediaSource(Uri.parse(videoUriList[0])),
                        buildMediaSource(Uri.parse(videoUriList[1])),
                        buildMediaSource(Uri.parse(videoUriList[2]))
       );
    }
```

*`RESULT:`* Using above scenario its playing videos in a correct sequence only, first of all it starts with str1... then after completion of str1, it moves to str2 and at the end it plays str3

***But***, If I am using *for loop* to achieve same result, I am *`facing an issue`*, it directly plays ***str3*** (3rd item of the list [i.e. - 2nd index]) in short, *skipping* str1 and str2 to play.

```
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayList.add(str1);
    arrayList.add(str2);
    arrayList.add(str3);

    if( null != arrayList) {

      Log.d("arrayList::", String.valueOf(arrayList.size()));

      for(int i=0; i<arrayList.size(); i++)
      {
        String string = arrayList.get(i);
        Log.d("string::", string+", "+String.valueOf(i));

        mediaSource = new ConcatenatingMediaSource(buildMediaSource(Uri.parse(string)));

        }

      }
```

My *LOG* says:

```
D/arrayList::: 3
D/string::: http://www.storiesinflight.com/js_videosub/jellies.mp4, 0
D/string::: http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/VfE_html5.mp4, 1
D/string::: http://www.html5videoplayer.net/videos/toystory.mp4, 2
```

***so where I am doing mistake, what went wrong in case of for loop***

Comment: Don't use code markdown to highlight words.

Comment: If this is about exoplayer, you should include the tag on the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call a constructor incrementally. You need to collect the arguments and then create the result. In this case, we can still use the loop to collect the values to an array, then pass that array to the constructor:

```
MediaSource[] mediaSources = new MediaSource[arrayList.size()];
for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
    String string = arrayList.get(i);
    Log.d("string::", string+", "+String.valueOf(i));
    mediaSources[i] = buildMediaSource(Uri.parse(string));
}
mediaSource = new ConcatenatingMediaSource(mediaSources);
```

Comment: Done. mediaSources[i] = buildMediaSource(Uri.parse(string));

Answer (score 1):

Your `for` loop sets your singular `mediaSource` on each iteration. However, there is only one - so after the loop executes, you have the **last** `mediaSource`. If you want to keep all of the `mediaSource`(s), you could use a corresponding `List`. Something like,

```
List<String> arrayList = Arrays.asList(str1, str2, str2);
List<ConcatenatingMediaSource> mediaSources = new ArrayList<>();
if (null != arrayList) {
    Log.d("arrayList::", String.valueOf(arrayList.size()));
    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
        String string = arrayList.get(i);
        Log.d("string::", string + ", " + String.valueOf(i));
        mediaSources.add(new ConcatenatingMediaSource(
                buildMediaSource(Uri.parse(string))));
    }
}
```